Create Joomla\CMS\Menu\MenuItem object
Friends,
in a custom module I'd like to create a Joomla\CMS\Menu\MenuItem object.
I guess it should work somehow like this:
$app = Factory::getApplication();     
$factory = $app->bootComponent('com_content')->getMVCFactory();
$my_menu_item = $factory->createModel('Menu', 'Site', ['ignore_request' => true]);

Any help?
